# Oracle Managed Data Access Bulk Copy ORA-39776: fatal Direct Path API error loading table

Tags: oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess, oracle.manageddataaccess, oraclebulkcopy

We've recently moved to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess in our application now it supports Bulk Copy

I am getting the following error when trying to copy a fairly large table.

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-39776: fatal Direct Path API error loading table SFOL.ENTITYTRANSACTIONLOG

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [klalbfrloc_10], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []'

The database is Oracle 19c and the ManagedDataAccess client is 19.10.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For errors such as Ora-00600 you have to use the following Oracle support documentation

```
ORA-600/ORA-7445/ORA-700 Error Look-up Tool (Doc ID 153788.1)
```

If you can't find anything related to the same "Code First Argument' which is in your case "klalbfrloc_10" you have to open SR ( Service request) maybe it's a bug and you need to patch or modify some parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing found in the tool. I'm trying to raise a Technical SR but our OPN Membership, though active and valid, isn't allowing it. Going to have to wait for the OPN team to get back to me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, the best option to wait or try to contact the account manager from your side and he will push